# Maximum value of $x$ such that $3^x-2^n$ is a prime.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers

> What is the maximum possible value of $x$ such that  expression $3^x - 2^n $ results in  a prime,
>   where $n$ is the maximum value such that $2^n<3^x$ and $2^{n+1} > 3^x$?

Using some brute force, till now I have found that $x = 33077 $ to be the maximum value for which the difference is a prime number. But is this the maximum value?

Can anyone please explain, for what values would we get a prime number.

Also, Would changing any of the constants from 2 and 3 to other values ,  give much more interesting results ? Would it be even solvable?

Comment: if I understand correctly (not clear):  take $x=17$.  then $n=\big \lfloor \frac {17}{\log_3(2)}\big \rfloor=26$, no?  But $3^{17}-2^{26}=62031299 = 11\times 23\times 245183$ is not a prime.

Comment: @lulu Thanks for pointing that out. the max value of x = 16.

Comment: $x=111$, $x=112$, (...?)

Comment: @Collag3n My computer isn't powerful enough.I am only telling the values for x < 75. If you re able to find higher powers , i would happily edit the question.

Comment: $x=16$ does not work either.  What is the context for this problem?  It seems to yield primes sometimes...not often.  Is there any reason to consider this form?

Comment: @lulu For x= 16 , we get 9492289 which is a prime number.Also , the reason to consider the question is for recreation and also for the weird beauty in it.

Comment: For $x=111$ the difference is 43407096013054584435417635156143349607274643631673579 (Prime) and for $x=112$ the difference is 82330802387104726482554560869982886833738333326783169 (Prime). I used PARI/GP, and it took less than a minute

Comment: Yes, $16$ does work.  My error.  Usually, with expressions like this, either there is some simple congruence between the values (not the case here) or there is an algebraic factorization (not the case here) or there's no way to attack the problem.  My guess is that this is the case here.

Comment: @lulu no problem. Although I also believe that their might not be a way to solve this, but this wierd distributions of primes makes me think that their is probably either an incredibly beautiful way or nothing :)

Comment: @Collag3n thanks for the values.

Comment: $x=193$, $x=405$, $x=495$, $x=1028$, .....For 1028, the difference is 6374161664241316681252619666285458514188063459809137762676070727725400956972560957618886628250893723032177356215343024518533290485181232350512697835877442932677137543898734628796583869434344977764717512750172647172160868557386442449298614757384183327386572745401384243980020033737601434533695121726204750470091212016075718193415271498546105369254465505530454328121165949886709803157294940450877610902347802035790055591808909403367516639922727218470401742298141572513318886342010622969172049

Comment: if I could only predict if $\lfloor{\log(3)\over \log(2)}\cdot x\rfloor$ were even or odd I might be able to restate the problem lol.

Comment: Would changing the the values of 2 and 3 in the equation with other numbers affect the solution??   Are their any numbers for which we get only the prime numbers?

Comment: probably on my end, I was trying to turn it into iterative sequences starting from 0 and conflating with sieve of sundaram.

Comment: There is likely no maximum. Compare this to Mersenne primes.

Comment: @DanielMathias I didn't understood your point.

Comment: Random thought: see if the powers of 3 from a pattern in binary. Subtracting the highest power of 2 means removing the leftmost digit.

Comment: @barrycarter Interesting method , but I don't see an obvious pattern.

Comment: my pattern was $2^{2z+1}=6a+2;2^{2z}=6b+4;3^z=6c+3$ with $a$ following a pattern of $a=0;a=4a+1$; $b$ in a pattern of $b=0;b=4b+2$ and $c$ following $c=0;c=3c+1$. $z$ is a natural, and by extension of the sieve of sundaram, $6(6de+d+e)+1$; $6(6de-d-e)+1$; $6(6de+d-e)-1$ and $6(6de-d+e)-1$ are all composite.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee What do we interpret from this? Can you please explain.

Comment: we are in effect, trying to figure out if the difference of two iterated linear polynomials or the difference of two iterated linear polynomials minus 1 can lead to a prime (on substition into the appropriate one of yet another pair of linear polynomials). the polynomials iterated, depend on if the exponent 2 is raised to is odd or even.

Comment: next $x=2236,x=5089,x=7938,x=14387$ and $x=21594$ (all probable primes).

Comment: Still , any lead on a pattern?

Comment: I am afraid that it has no pattern

Comment: Why not using th Bertrand's postulate ?

Comment: @The.old.crap How do we implement that here ?

Comment: @The Demonix_Hermit sorry we have to find a better result than the Bertrand's postulate or refines it wich is something too hard.Maybe using probabilistic argument there is no maximum.

Comment: Should I still keep this question open for solutions and discussion (If you think that the question is possible to solve )?

Comment: It seems that x = 33077 is the next value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't prove anything, but I will suggest that there are probably infinitely many $x$ for which this value is prime by the standard heuristics that one might use for these problems and also that this problem is very similar to long-standing open questions, so probably not easily answered.

For the first part, the prime number theorem is often interpreted as saying:

> If we choose a natural number $n$ at random, the probability that it is prime is roughly $1/\log(n)$.

This is not a formal statement - not least because "random" and "probability" are involved with "natural number" but without any further specification - but it is commonly used and is close enough to statements that really do follow from the prime number theorem.

Using this alone, we can note that $3^x-2^n$ is definitely no bigger than $3^x$, so has about a $\frac{1}{\log(3)x}$ chance of being prime. The expected number of primes would then be the sum of this over all integer $x$, which is the harmonic series and is infinite - suggesting infinitely many primes.

If we're being a bit more careful, we might look at each $p$: the sequence $3^x-2^n$ will take on every value that can possibly be represented as a difference of a power of $3$ with a power of $2$ mod $p$ since $n=\lfloor\log_2(3)\cdot x\rfloor$ and $\log_2(3)$ is irrational, meaning that mod $p-1$, the pair $(x,n)$ could obtain any possible two values due to the equidistribution theorem and actually obtains every possible pair equally often - so the proportion of values of $3^x-2^n$ that a given $p$ divides is precisely equal to the probability that, if we choose a random power of $3$ and a random power of $2$ mod $p$ that they are equal - which, doesn't create any *clear* conspiracies that would contradict our heuristic, although this probability is greater than $1/p$, which is sort of what the heuristic would have suggested - how much greater, I don't know. (But also, the fact that it is greater than $1/p$ is somewhat counteracted by the lack of independence between this condition holding for various primes simultaneously)

However, this brings us to the second part: it is not known whether there are infinitely Mersenne primes - that is, primes of the form $2^n-1$. This has been a prominent open question for a while, and it touches on a lot of the same issues that arise in yours - which suggests that this is a question that is beyond the current reach of mathematics. (But maybe that will change someday!)

Comment: you mean $\lfloor\log_2(3)\cdot x\rfloor$?

Comment: @Collag3n Yes, thanks.

Comment: @MiloBrandt Thanks for explaining it properly !! But I will still keep the question open for some time for discussion before accepting your answer.

Answer (score 1):

COMMENT

Some of these type of primes may have a relation with Merssene and Fermat numbers:

$$N=3^x-2^n=3^x-2-2^n+2=3^x-2-2(2^n-1)$$

Where $M=2^n-1$ is Merssene Number. Also:

$$N=3^x-2^n=3^x+2-2^n -2=3^x+2 -2(2^n +1)$$

If $n=2^m$ then $F=2^n+1$ is a Fermat number.The  equal  linear form of N is:

$$N=3^x-2^n=3^x-(3-1)^n=3q ±1$$

depending on n (even or odd).$S=3q ±1$ can generate of a set of infinitely many primes, therefore set of primes like N is the subset of S.It is not known such primes has a limit.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation part !

Comment: You are welcome.